# Wordpress 4.7 call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-4.7

Updated to WordPress 4.7, and am receiving this error when I have one of my custom-made plugins enabled:

```
( ! ) Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in /home/vagrant/Sites/wordpress/wp includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298
```

I also get this with my debugging enabled: [image]

I am uncertain as to what the issue is, as the stack trace seems rather cryptic. Any advice on what may have broken the plugin, or how to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Can you show us the source code of your plugin?

Comment: Here is the SVN repository: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/rsvpify-rsvp-form/

Comment: Hello,

add_action('plugins_loaded', $this->plugin_update());
check this line in your plugin something here you need modified
go to admin->class-rsvpify-embedd-admin.php

Comment: I am not sure I understand -- is there something wrong with that method in particular, or the way I am calling it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Afzal mentioned this line is problematic:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', $this->plugin_update());
```

We can replicate the error you got with this simple example:

```
class Test
{
    public function init()
    {
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', $this->plugin_update() );
    }

    public function plugin_update()
    {
    }
}

$obj = new Test;
$obj->init();
```

The usual way around this problem is to replace:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', $this->plugin_update() );
```

with:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'plugin_update' ) );
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Need to wait 10 hours before I can award you the bounty, though.